# Start the example on a new line

Tags: line-breaking, amsthm

I'm using the following code to write out examples and solutions in my book. However, I'd like to start the example in a new line after the heading. Currently, this is what I have as the output.

[image]

```
\newtheoremstyle{examplestyle}% name of the style
{}% Space above
{}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font (not in italics)
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries}% Theorem head font (bold)
{.}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning 'normal')

% Use the custom style for questions
\theoremstyle{examplestyle}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
```

Comment: Please always provide examples as a full small test document. I am guessing you are using `amsthm` but `\newtheoremstyle` is not defined by default and you have not said how you have defined it.

Comment: If it is `amsthm` you can use `\newline` for `{.5em}% Space after theorem head`  (see note 3 at that point in the amsthm manual)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for the response. That worked. Yes I'm using asthm. This is my first post, so I take note of the small test document.

Answer (score 2):

The comments in your code come from the amsthm manual

[image]

and as noted there, in note 3, you can replace

```
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
```

by

```
{\newline}
```

To force a newline after the theorem heading in this style.